# Symfony 2 Controller Test without virtualhost

Tags: symfony

How can I run a controller test without virtualhost on symfony 2? My project is under web root "http://localhost/Symfony/web/"

```
public function testIndex() {
    $client = static::createClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/home');
    $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->getStatusCode() == '200');
    $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('title:contains("MyTitle")')->count() > 0);
}
```

The test above tries to request "http://localhost/home", I tried changing request to full url but It doesn't work yet

Does anyone knows how could I fix it?

Comment: Where is your front controller `app_dev.php`? In `/Symfony` or `/Symfony/web`? Suppose you have your webapp in `~/projects/my-webapp`, a symlink from `~/projects/my-webapp/web` to `/var/www/Symfony` should allow you to browse the webapp using `http://localhost/Symfony`, `http://localhost/Symfony/home`.

Comment: It is in /Symfony/web but adding symlink won't solve since unit test tries to access localhost/home